# Maintain index while filter model from Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection as

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
       name: '',
       author: ''
    }
});

var BookCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Book
});


/*** Populate the Collection ***/

var b1 = new Book({name: 'Java programming', author: 'John Doe'});
var b2 = new Book({name: 'C# programming', author: 'Alice Jane'});
var b3 = new Book({name: 'SQL in depth', author: 'James Wayne'});

var bkCollection = new BookCollection();

bkCollection.push(b1);
bkCollection.push(b2);
bkCollection.push(b3);

//I want to remove all models where name contains word 'programming'

var RESTRICTED = 'programming';

bkCollection.each(function(book){
    if(book.get('name').indexOf(RESTRICTED) > -1){
        bkCollection.remove(book);
    }
});
```

However, I end up getting undefined model and programming title in some cases when there are large number of records  (> 100)

What is the correct way to filter out a model from a collection in Backbone ?

Answer (score 0):

The line `bkCollection.remove(book);` is removing a model from a collection as it iterates over it. Instead push the models into an array and then remove from collection.

```js
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
       name: '',
       author: ''
    }
});

var BookCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Book
});


/*** Populate the Collection ***/

var b1 = new Book({name: 'Java programming', author: 'John Doe'});
var b2 = new Book({name: 'C# programming', author: 'Alice Jane'});
var b3 = new Book({name: 'SQL in depth', author: 'James Wayne'});

var bkCollection = new BookCollection();

bkCollection.push(b1);
bkCollection.push(b2);
bkCollection.push(b3);

//I want to remove all models where name contains word 'programming'

var RESTRICTED = 'programming';

var booksToRemove = new Array(); //cfa: the array that will hold the books to be removed
bkCollection.each(function(book){
    if((book.get('name').indexOf(RESTRICTED)) > -1){
        booksToRemove.push(book); // cfa: push the model into the array
    }
});

bkCollection.remove(booksToRemove); // remove from collection

console.log('Updated Collection is ' + JSON.stringify(bkCollection));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is removing models during the iteration as bvoleti already mentioned. You can easily fix this by using the built in methods like [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) instead of `each`:

```
var RESTRICTED = 'programming';
var matches = bkCollection.filter(function(book){
  return book.get('name').indexOf(RESTRICTED) > -1;
});
bkCollection.remove(matches);
```